# Is it possible to have 2 view controllers from 2 different storyboards to be active on the screen simultaneously?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4, xcode10

I am trying to develop something on the lines of the Uber app. I have to keep the 2 view controllers in separate storyboards. I need to pull up a drawer like in Uber over a View controller which has a scnview. In simpler term and taking Uber as an example, I need a way to accomplish the same interaction where the mapViewController is in one storyboard and the drawer having the driver details to be in another storyboard.

Comment: You can split up your scenes between several storyboards by using storyboard refs.  I have a feeling, though, that you're misusing the word storyboard here.  Do you actually mean "scene" rather than "storyboard"?  A storyboard is a file, whereas a scene is the "window" (not really but..) within a storyboard that usually is represented as a UIViewController.  If you meant scene, please update your question... and the answer is to use a container view.

Comment: Yeah, I did mean a storyboard. They will be present in 2 different files and repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this feature in many other ways as well,

But answer to your question is - Yes you can display more than one controller at the same time on screen.

You can use `ContainerView` like this :

[image]

And using Storyboard reference, you can contain UIViewController of another storyboard's controller.

Comment: is there a way I can programmatically attach the storyboard reference? Pretty new to this :)

Comment: @nTri there actually isn’t a class called UIContainerView so please improve your answer. Anika, container view is a strategy for a UIView that can be implemented in code and/or appear as a UI object in the InterfaceBuilder object types bin such that when dragged out into a scene, will create a few UIViews (one in the new container scene) and an embed segue. See this [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: @Smartcat I have not used word class anywhere if you check again..!!

Comment: Well what is this “UIContainerView” you referred to? “UI” as a prefix is reserved by Apple, so what Apple class or protocol or whatever are you referring to?  This will confuse people. InterfaceBuilder’s Library pane has a “Container View”.  I know there are others on SO who make this same error, but let’s set this right.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you using containerView you can do this.

**Step 1:** Set up a Reference of storyboard

[image]

**Step 2:** Select Embed  at above Picture

**Step 3:** this is your second storyboard with entry point [image]

**Step 4:** This is your output

[image]