# Swift 4 Ios same UIView at multiple screens

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to program a board games. There are multiple screens (game board, cards etc). At every screen I want the same status View at the buttom (to show how much money etc the player owns)

I created an UIView like this in a new file to use it globally:

```
let Resourcen=classResourcen()

class classResourcen: UIView {

init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 98, y: 1006, width: 739, height: 360))

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 739, height: 360)
    self.addSubview(imageView)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I use it in my my first storyboard screen:

```
self.view.addSubview(Resourcen)
```

If I add it to a 2nd storyboard sceen it works as well - but when I go back for my first page it disappears.
I read one cannot use an UIView multiple times. Now I wonder what I should do instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53076954/5725512 follow this

Comment: Hi did you try to set your viewController in an other one (using a containerView in Storyboard) ? Then you set you view in the main ViewController. You would also add your view to the application window in order to always keep above all your Views. You would also add a new window with an other window level. Hope it helps :)

Comment: please, describe or attach screens of layout and how you want to reuse this view.

Comment: Why do you use a view globally...please do not do this, just use it multiple times, there is no problem using the same `UIView` subclass multiple times...

Comment: Why you want use same instance in different screens? You can just create two different instance of classResourcen, something like this:   addSubview(classResourcen())

Comment: The layout is like a coin with a number in it. When I do something in other parts of the screen the number changes

Comment: A `UIView` instance can have only one `superview`. You need to alloc/init a different one each time.

Comment: in my UIView I store several variables like the amount of money. If I work with the same subclass multiple times these variables wont get updated I think.
But when thinking about it storing variables in a UIView-class might be the mistake?

Comment: you can create a sharedInstance of your view and use that everywhere may it helps you

Comment: I think if you can use a containers it would be the best aproach because you dont need to add the view that is being reused on different viewController every time when going on that controller.I use add a container view on the first controller where you put your all gave stuf and the score view is just at the bottom of the container and give the navigation controller to the first view and then the score view is always remain at the bottom.
Thanks.

Comment: Mhh the problem is I have like 3 screens where I need exactly the same View at the buttom. And then a 4th screen without it. Container view wont work cause I dont need it everytime

Comment: I use variables with "didSet" in my view. I for example variable money changes "didset" starts to update the view.
Cause of this using one class View (with several instances) and one class with variables like money doesnt work either I think.

Comment: your view should be getting any information that it displays from a model so creating it multiple times shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make this view in another file or in .xib.